# How to get a claim back?

Tags: offworld-trading-company

If I mis-clicked and placed a wrong building or built one at a wrong place, how can I get the spent claim back? If I bulldoze the building I'm not getting my claim back, and sometimes when this happens there is no good way forward without restarting the game/forfeiting. It might be the designers' grand idea that the player should be omnipotent-like and remember exactly what resources they will need so they never forget to place a crucial building before running out of claims, but most likely I've simply missed it.

So what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to get a claim back once the tile has been used. This is a design decision: you are forced to think ahead how to use a limited resource.

There is one exception that I am aware of: if one bulldoze the tile before it is built, the claim is returned. So miss-clicks can be corrected if you immediately realize it or if the game is on pause.

Update: As mentioned by DMA57361 in a comment, if another player beats you to the tile, your claim is refunded as well.

Comment: In the same vein as "if one bulldoze the tile before it is built" you will also get back your claim if you and another player went for the same tile and they get there before you.

Comment: @DMA57361 True. But that's outside one's own control.

Answer (score 1):

If you misclick, you can delete the building and return the claim- as long as the building hasn't been completed you can get your claim back.

If you build a building that later becomes useless, demolish it and use the tile for something else. This is intentionally part of the game and a vital strategy.

Finally, the "return claim" was added to the black market in Jupiter's Forge. Nomadic HQs get one for free with each level, or they can be purchased (each purchase providing two uses). This is best for unneeded resources that are too far from your HQ to turn into manufacturing buildings.